# How can I replace a value if the value in the column title?

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace

I have dataframe as below.
I want to replace value to 1 if each column title in A1.
[image]

This is my expected output.

[image]

Comment: Are there are many columns? or just three columns?

Comment: @GilseungAhn There are many columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your data frame `df`, and assume 2, 3, ... columns are the words.

Then use one of the following codes.

Code 1. Using `.str.contains()`

```
word_list = df.columns.tolist()[1:]
for word in word_list:
    df[word] = df['A1'].str.contains(word).astype(int)
```

Code 2. Using `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer`

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
word_list = df.columns.tolist()[1:]

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary = word_list)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['A1']).toarray()
X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns = word_list)
output = pd.concat([df['A1'], X], axis = 1)
```